# Python3 SyntaxError: expected an indented block

Tags: python-3.x, motordriver

I want my program to be :
when I enter '3' key to from the main menu selection > 'N' key to return back to the main menu selection.

But now It state "the expected an indented block" at

```
def Menu():
```

This is my full coding :

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Slush
import math
import time
import sys

from inputs import get_key
from time import sleep


b = Slush.sBoard()
m = [Slush.Motor(0), Slush.Motor(1), Slush.Motor(2), Slush.Motor(3)]

m[0].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[1].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[2].setMaxSpeed(250)
m[3].setMaxSpeed(150)

m[0].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[1].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)
m[2].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[3].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 50)
pwm.start(0)
GPIO.output(18, 1)


def Menu():
print("Please Enter Number From List Below:")
print("1: Start Program")
print("2: Control Manually")
print("3: Exit Program")
inputkey = int(input("Enter a number & Press Enter:"))


#START PROGRAM
if inputkey == 1:
    print("Press Home Key To Start Program")
#def_StartProgram()

    while 1:
        events = get_key()
        for event in events:
                if event.code == 'KEY_HOME':
                    print("PROGRAM START")
                    print("\nMotor0 Position is", m[0].getPosition())
                    print("\nMotor1 Position is", m[1].getPosition())
                    print("\nMotor2 Position is", m[2].getPosition())
                    print("\nMotor3 Position is", m[3].getPosition())
                    m[1].goTo(-10000)
                    time.sleep(3)
                    print("\nMotor1 Position is", m[1].getPosition())


#CONTROL MANUAL
if inputkey == 2:
    print("Manual Mode")

    while 1:
        events = get_key()
        for event in events:

            if event.code == 'KEY_Q':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[0].isBusy(): m[0].run(1, 35)
            if event.code == 'KEY_A':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[0].isBusy(): m[0].softStop()
            if event.code == 'KEY_Z':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[0].isBusy(): m[0].run(0, 35)



            if event.code == 'KEY_W':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[1].isBusy(): m[1].run(1, 20)
            if event.code == 'KEY_S':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[1].isBusy(): m[1].softStop()
            if event.code == 'KEY_X':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[1].isBusy(): m[1].run(0, 20)



            if event.code == 'KEY_E':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[2].isBusy(): m[2].run(1, 100)
            if event.code == 'KEY_D':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[2].isBusy(): m[2].softStop()
            if event.code == 'KEY_C':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[2].isBusy(): m[2].run(0, 100)




            if event.code == 'KEY_R':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[3].isBusy(): m[3].run(1, 10)
            if event.code == 'KEY_F':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[3].isBusy(): m[3].softStop()
            if event.code == 'KEY_V':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not m[3].isBusy(): m[3].run(0, 10)



            if event.code == 'KEY_1':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(1)
                    sleep(0.5)
                    if not pwm.stop(): pwm.start(0)


            if event.code == 'KEY_3':
                value = event.state
                if value == 1:
                    if not pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0): pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(99)

#EXIT PROGRAM
if inputkey == 3:
    print("Press 'Y/N' key = Exit/Back To Menu ")


    while 1:
        events = get_key()
        for event in events:

            if event.code == 'KEY_Y':
                sys.exit(0)
            if event.code == 'KEY_N':
                Menu()
```

This is how I want my program to work. FLOW CHART :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8Rhc.png)

Comment: Python is space sensitive. Everything in a function block must be indented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed indentation in the *def Menu*. Please try the following code, since I don't know you exact logic, so the program might not work as per your need, but you will get a fair idea on the logic.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import Slush
import math
import time
import sys

from inputs import get_key
from time import sleep


b = Slush.sBoard()
m = [Slush.Motor(0), Slush.Motor(1), Slush.Motor(2), Slush.Motor(3)]

m[0].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[1].setMaxSpeed(150)
m[2].setMaxSpeed(250)
m[3].setMaxSpeed(150)

m[0].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[1].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)
m[2].setCurrent(150, 150, 150, 150)
m[3].setCurrent(100, 100, 100, 100)


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
pwm = GPIO.PWM(18, 50)
pwm.start(0)
GPIO.output(18, 1)

def Menu():
    while 1:    
        print("Please Enter Number From List Below:")
        print("1: Start Program")
        print("2: Control Manually")
        print("3: Exit Program")
        inputkey = int(input("Enter a number & Press Enter:"))


        #START PROGRAM
        if inputkey == 1:
            print("Press Home Key To Start Program")
        #def_StartProgram()

            while 1:
                events = get_key()
                for event in events:
                        if event.code == 'KEY_HOME':
                            print("PROGRAM START")
                            print("\nMotor0 Position is", m[0].getPosition())
                            print("\nMotor1 Position is", m[1].getPosition())
                            print("\nMotor2 Position is", m[2].getPosition())
                            print("\nMotor3 Position is", m[3].getPosition())
                            m[1].goTo(-10000)
                            time.sleep(3)
                            print("\nMotor1 Position is", m[1].getPosition())


        #CONTROL MANUAL
        if inputkey == 2:
            print("Manual Mode")

            while 1:
                events = get_key()
                for event in events:

                    if event.code == 'KEY_Q':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[0].isBusy(): m[0].run(1, 35)
                    if event.code == 'KEY_A':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[0].isBusy(): m[0].softStop()
                    if event.code == 'KEY_Z':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[0].isBusy(): m[0].run(0, 35)



                    if event.code == 'KEY_W':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[1].isBusy(): m[1].run(1, 20)
                    if event.code == 'KEY_S':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[1].isBusy(): m[1].softStop()
                    if event.code == 'KEY_X':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[1].isBusy(): m[1].run(0, 20)



                    if event.code == 'KEY_E':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[2].isBusy(): m[2].run(1, 100)
                    if event.code == 'KEY_D':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[2].isBusy(): m[2].softStop()
                    if event.code == 'KEY_C':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[2].isBusy(): m[2].run(0, 100)




                    if event.code == 'KEY_R':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[3].isBusy(): m[3].run(1, 10)
                    if event.code == 'KEY_F':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[3].isBusy(): m[3].softStop()
                    if event.code == 'KEY_V':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not m[3].isBusy(): m[3].run(0, 10)



                    if event.code == 'KEY_1':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(1)
                            sleep(0.5)
                            if not pwm.stop(): pwm.start(0)


                    if event.code == 'KEY_3':
                        value = event.state
                        if value == 1:
                            if not pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(0): pwm.ChangeDutyCycle(99)

        #EXIT PROGRAM
        if inputkey == 3:
            print("Press 'Y/N' key = Exit/Back To Menu ")

            exit_flag = True
            while exit_flag:
                events = get_key()
                for event in events:

                    if event.code == 'KEY_Y':
                        sys.exit(0)
                    elif event.code == 'KEY_N':
                        exit_flag = False
                        break
Menu()
```

Comment: sorry I did not understand, how to fix it.?

Comment: I have updated the answer kindly check now and let me know if you need any more explaination

Comment: There is no error but the program not working as I want. I upload a basic flowchart that how I want my program to run.

Comment: have you written this code from scratch or took reference from somewhere else?

Comment: I reference from many source, Yes I write the code just combine it. Im using slushengine motordriver.

Comment: I have made another update, try to execute the following code. But since I don't have knowledge of RashberryPi so I'm not able to help you much with the logic.

Comment: It can run with no error but the menu selection do not appear. Anyway thanks for your help. Im just new learner of raspberry pi.

Comment: yes this time the menu selection appear as I want, unfortunately if I select '3' exit program and then press key to go back to the menu selection this does not work. The menu selection wont go back.

Comment: try the update code now. I have added a flag for the particular option

Comment: when I select '3' and then ENTER, the menu selection just appeared immediately. It should be when when I choose '3' and ENTER , it should ask Press Y/N key and then when I select N , then it should go back to the menu selection.

Comment: Try the new updated code now. But I think you should start fixing the code yourself now. Since it is all the syntax error is fixed and now it is logical issue which you should be able to fix.

Comment: thanks @argo for your help, your code I help me a lot. I will improvised it :)

Comment: Glad I could help.